# all text views are selecting when one textview select through on click listener in android?

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

i am developing an application for quiz.in my xml i have a question, 4 options(options are textviews)and previous and next buttons . i did previous and next buttons. but i am facing problem with options. when i click or select option for one question, all questions options also selecting. how to control this behaviour? please any one help how to do it?

```
   if (v == rb1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      //   quelay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       // answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
        setNext();
    if (v == rb2) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      //   quelay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       // answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
        setNext();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 private View.OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            // Yes we will handle click here but which button clicked??? We don't know

            // So we will make
            switch (v.getId() /*to get clicked view id**/) {
                case R.id.rb1:

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //quelay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
                     setNext();

                    break;
                case R.id.rb2:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb2.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //quelay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
                     setNext();

                    break;
                case R.id.rb3:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb3.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //quelay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
                     setNext();

                    break;

                case R.id.rb4:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb4.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //quelay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
                     setNext();

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
if (v == rb1) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
    setNext();
if (v == rb2) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb2.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    db.updateContact(question.getText().toString());
    setNext();
```

you show *rb1.getText().toString()* in both conditons. so change your second condition part like,

```
if (v == rb2) 
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb2.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```